# pass a DateTime value using Jquery to Action method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetime

i am trying to pass a Datetime value using jquery to controller but its showing me the error

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'FromDate' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Report(System.String, System.String,
>   System.DateTime, System.DateTime, Int32, Int32, Int32)' 
>   but while debugging i am getting the value. i am generating a report for this but can not able to sort this out . please help what is the problem.

View

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Report", new { id = "PDF" })" class="btn-primary" id="exportbutton"> Export as PDF&nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i></a>&nbsp;


@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromDate, new { @readonly = true, @class = "date-picker form-control" }) 
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ToDate, new { @readonly = true, @class = "date-picker form-control" }) 
     $('#exportbutton').click(function () {
            var accountType = $('#SelectedAccountType').val(); 
            var fromDate = $('#FromDate').val();
            var toDate = $('#ToDate').val();
            var accountId = $('#SelectedAccount').val();
            var userId = $('#SelectedUser').val(); 
            var teamId = $('#SelectedTeam').val();
            var id = "PDF";
            $.post(
                '@Url.Action("Report", "Reports")',
                { id: id, SelectedAccountType: accountType, FromDate: fromDate, ToDate: toDate, SelectedAccount: accountId, SelectedUser: userId, SelectedTeam: teamId },
                 function (data) {
                 });
        });
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Report(string id, string SelectedAccountType, DateTime FromDate, DateTime ToDate, int SelectedAccount, int SelectedTeam, int SelectedUser)
        {
            LocalReport lr = new LocalReport();
            string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Report"), "ReportList1.rdlc");
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                lr.ReportPath = path;
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Index");
            }
            var OrderInfoList = reportService.GetReportsList(SelectedAccountType, FromDate, ToDate, SelectedAccount, SelectedTeam, SelectedUser);
            ReportDataSource rd = new ReportDataSource("MyDataSet", OrderInfoList);
            lr.DataSources.Add(rd);
            string reportType = id;
            string mimeType;
            string encoding;
            string fileNameExtension;
            string deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo>" +
            "  <OutputFormat>" + id + "</OutputFormat>" +
            "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
            "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
            "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
            "  <MarginLeft>0.5in</MarginLeft>" +
            "  <MarginRight>0.5in</MarginRight>" +
            "  <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>" +
            "</DeviceInfo>";

            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streams;
            byte[] renderedBytes;

            renderedBytes = lr.Render(
                reportType,
                deviceInfo,
                out mimeType,
                out encoding,
                out fileNameExtension,
                out streams,
                out warnings);
            return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);
        }
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Try passing it as `var fromDate = new Date($('#FromDate').val());
            var toDate = new Date($('#ToDate').val())`. Are you using any plugin for dateTime like `datePicker`?

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao yes i am using datepicker

Comment: which one? `jquery` or `bootstrap`? can you give the link of the plugin?? You might also need to post your `model`!

Comment: i am using Jquery datepicker

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#exportbutton').click(function () {
      var accountType = $('#SelectedAccountType').val(); 
      var fromDate = new Date($('#FromDate').datepicker('getDate'));//Get it from datepicker, this will get the selected date.
      var toDate = new Date($('#ToDate').datepicker('getDate'));
      var accountId = $('#SelectedAccount').val();
      var userId = $('#SelectedUser').val(); 
      var teamId = $('#SelectedTeam').val();
      var id = "PDF";
      $.post(
           '@Url.Action("Report", "Reports")',
            { id: id, SelectedAccountType: accountType, FromDate: fromDate, ToDate: toDate, SelectedAccount: accountId, SelectedUser: userId, SelectedTeam: teamId },
            function (data) {
      });
});
```

Comment: This is also not working, while executing in console getting strange result.
var fromDate = new Date($('#FromDate').datepicker('getDate'));

Comment: Can you post that result here.

Comment: its not giving me that date of date picker. what it gives is here on console.
Date($('#FromDate').datepicker('getDate'));
"Fri Jun 05 2015 15:06:40 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

it is showing me todays date

Comment: console.log($('#FromDate').datepicker('getDate'))
and it gives null undefined

Comment: and what does $('#FromDate').val() gives??

Comment: it gives "06/03/2015"

Comment: @reshav check **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/fgbr8c44/)** I've prepared for you!! You will get to know which method fetchs what type of objects

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you pass the dates as a string and then convert them to a date.

```
 public ActionResult Report(string id, string SelectedAccountType, string FromDate, string ToDate, int SelectedAccount, int SelectedTeam, int SelectedUser)
   {
     to_date = Convert.ToDateTime(ToDate);
       ////
   }
```